# Typescript - Import vs "declare var" with type definitions

Tags: typescript

Building an Angular 2 app using Typescript, I am attempting to import the popular `d3` library.

I have installed the type definitions using `TSD`, and I am referencing the `tsd.d.ts` file correctly:

`/// <reference path="../../../tools/typings/tsd/tsd.d.ts" />`

Now, I want to `import` my `d3` node_module. It was installed via `NPM`:

```
/// <reference path="../../../tools/typings/tsd/tsd.d.ts" />
import * as d3 from 'd3/d3';
```

This works, but I don't get any benefit from my type definitions. My IDE is not providing any type-ahead info or syntax highlighting. If I change it to this:

```
/// <reference path="../../../tools/typings/tsd/tsd.d.ts" />
import * as d3 from 'd3/d3';
```

I now get all of the syntax highlighting/type-ahead definitions that I am expecting. However, my app is looking for a file at `node_modules/d3.js` which doesn't exist, so this obviously doesn't work.

When I change my import statement to a `var` declaration, my app compiles correctly and I get all the appropriate typescript definitions:

```
/// <reference path="../../../tools/typings/tsd/tsd.d.ts" />
declare var d3 = require('d3/d3');
```

So, my question is simply what is the right approach? What is the difference in `import` vs `declare var`, and is there a way to get type definitions when using `import` if they are not included in the npm module itself?

I've noticed things like `import {Component} from 'angular2/core';` work fine, but the type definitions are included within the same directory as the javascript file I am importing.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using.

Comment: @JMac I'm trying to get d3 to work with TypeScript too. Did you get this working in the end? Is your project open source?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`import * as d3 from 'd3/d3';` should work fine with the type system (without the `///<reference .../>`) as long as the compiler options are correct, and the folder structure is correct in the typings folder.

`declare var d3` is how to declare a variable that exists somewhere in the JS. Think of it like "Yeah yeah typescript, quit complaining, trust me it exists".

`import {Component} from 'angular/core';` is how to pull a specific piece from a module. In node terms this translates to `var Component = require('angular/core').Component;`

The important compiler option to have on is `"moduleResolution": "node"`, which should already be on for angular to function.

So if `d3` was installed as a node_module then you should be able to simply use:

```
npm install d3
npm install --save-dev @types/d3
tsc
```

then

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Comment: for others who are first-stepping with typescript (like me), 'tsd' had been deprecated in favor of 'typings'

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. This step 
{ npm install d3,
  tsd install d3,
  tsc } equals to----> npm install @types/d3 then, the import step right??

Comment: @Rishi It's possible that `d3` is a dependency of `@types/d3` which would cause your scenario to work. However the preferred approach is probably `npm install d3` then `npm install --save-dev @types/d3` so that you put the dependencies in the right spots in the `package.json`. `@types/d3` is not needed at runtime, only compile time, so users of your package / prod versions of your site do not need the extra files, so they can be safely ignored.